# How to compare two value of column in mysql

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.7

Hi I have two table in mysql database 
and stored values like this

```
    @v1(column for 1s table) = '1,2,3,4'
    @v2(column for 2nd table) = '1,2,3,4,5,6,7'
```

I want to compare them and return true is anything matches.
Any help would be appreciated.

return true if any value matches
else false

Comment: `Hi I have two table` ... no, those are two strings.  It would be difficult to work with such CSV data and you should normalize your tables.

Comment: Hi  @TimBiegeleisen I know it is bit difficult, but I have to store in that way only.

Comment: What mean `anything matches` ?

Comment: Nobody has to do anything. Least of all THIS!